# powershell install Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 package fail "can not find any package"

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps

I create UWS simple package in the visual studio 2015. Then install the package to my windows 10 virtual machine via powershell is work. I can see the app in my start menu and run it is OK.

I want to install the package to my PAD windows 10(10586.29). Copy the package folder **"UWSHellowWord_1.0.1.0_Test"** to the document folder. Long click the file **"UWSHellowWord_1.0.1.0_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1"** shows a menu then choose the **"use powershell execute"** to install this package.

The powershell shows me an error message "Error: can not find any package or resource in the command directory. Please make sure The packages you want to install packages or resource are placed in the same directory". I don't know how to fix it. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for programming tools _tutorial_ or _guide_ rather than for a particular programming issue itself. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will get help on super user.

Answer (score 1):

Run powershell (as administrator)

navigate to directory ""UWSHellowWord_1.0.1.0_Test"

Type - `powershell Set-Executionpolicy RemoteSigned`

Type `.\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1`

and check